# My Website Encounters Internal Server Error Despite Tested Okay Multiple Times on VS Code Studio Before Uploading My Files

Tags: python, for-loop, flask, typeerror, internal-server-error

Here are snippets of my code running on Flask.

```
import json
import requests

from error import error
from requests import Session
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/chart")
def chart():

    url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=24h&locale=en"
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(response.text)

    crypto = []

    for i in data:
        dictdata = {}
        dictdata["rank"] = i["market_cap_rank"]
        dictdata["name"] = i["name"]
        dictdata["symbol"] = i["symbol"].upper()

        if i["current_price"] >= 1:
            dictdata["price"] = "${:,.2f}".format(i["current_price"])
        else:
            dictdata["price"] = "${:,.8f}".format(i["current_price"])

        dictdata["change"] = round(i["price_change_percentage_24h_in_currency"], 2)

        crypto.append(dictdata)

    return render_template("chart.html", crypto=crypto)
```

I tested all my codes by running Flask Run and everything ran smoothly. However when I deployed my Flask code on pythonanywhere.com, I always encounter "Internal Server Error" on one particular page of my website and it's coming from the abovementioned code.

I checked the error log from pythonanywhere.com and it stated that I have "**TypeError: string indices must be integers**" when running this line of code below.

> dictdata["rank"] = i["market_cap_rank"]

So is there really something wrong with my code or are there some additional dependencies or libraries that I need to install on the web server?

Comment: Yes, there is a mistake in your code, it tries to use `i` as if it were a dictionary, but it does not account for the possibility that it is a string.

Comment: The JSON data returned by `api.coingecko.com` seems not to be what you expect.